# localstorage json rows how do i access each row and their individual elements

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic3

#### How can I access to a localStorage item?

In this case I have the following array of objects in the localStorage:

```
[
  {
    "id1":"my_id",
    "title":"My_title",
    "subject":"subject1"
  },
  {
    "id2":"my_id",
    "title":"My_title2",
    "subject":"subject2"
  },
  {
     "id3":"my_id",
     "title":"My_title3",
     "subject":"subject3"
  },
  {
    "id4":"my_id",
    "title":"My_title4",
    "subject":"subject4"
  }
]
```

Please can anyone help me with this.
I want to access this from localStorage data.

Comment: What is key of this data in localstorage?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `localStorage` data using the [getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) method of the Storage interface.

```
// just change [my-local-storage-data-key] string for your actual data key on localStorage
const data = localStorage.getItem("[my-local-storage-data-key]");
const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
// -> jsonData holds your array of objects
```

Read more about [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

---

```js
// copy the following to your browser console and check outputs
// trying to run this code snippet will fail because the document is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin' flag."

const myDataArray = [
  {
    "id1":"my_id",
    "title":"My_title",
    "subject":"subject1"
  },
  {
    "id2":"my_id",
    "title":"My_title2",
    "subject":"subject2"
  },
  {
     "id3":"my_id",
     "title":"My_title3",
     "subject":"subject3"
  },
  {
    "id4":"my_id",
    "title":"My_title4",
    "subject":"subject4"
  }
];

// saving to localStorage with `rows` as key
const serializedData = JSON.stringify(myDataArray);
localStorage.setItem('rows', serializedData);

// retrieving data from localStorage `rows` key
const data = localStorage.getItem('rows');
const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

console.log('jsonData from localStorage:', jsonData);
// -> jsonData from localStorage: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
console.log('jsonData[0]:', jsonData[0]);
// -> jsonData[0]: {id1: "my_id", title: "My_title", subject: "subject1"}

// remove localStorage item `rows`
localStorage.removeItem('rows');
```

Comment: console.log('jsonData[0]:', jsonData[0]); gives me undefined as output

Comment: Can you provide more info about that? Browser? Screenshot? (Are you using the correct storage key?)